# CSS file not loading changes

Tags: css

I'm really new to Magento and really confused of what's going on in there. I need to fix IE 8 bugs so I create a new css file in my theme directory. I link the css file in the head.phtml with conditional css comment. So far so good. I clean all the cache, browser, magento. Disable the css files merge, flushing css cache. I see that the declaration "" is in the header. But when I write something in the file and refresh the page in IE 8 (in compatibility mode) changes does not take effect. I need some help guys.
Thanks in advance!

This is what I've added to my head.phtml file:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/frontend/ft001-sofia/mod/css/ie8-fix.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here's the website. You can see the head with Inspect Element:

```
http://dev.elmaira.bg/
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code of the way you've added it in the head.phtml, maybe a screenshot of the page source and what you tried to change

Comment: Yes, sure. Look at my post. I'll add it!

Comment: maybe stating the obvious but are you sure the CSS is being loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure. How I can be sure about that?

Comment: You can use the dev tool or firebug for IE

Comment: You still have CSS merging enabled and only turned of js merging, judging from: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cssmedia/394c6e8317d42dfb1676289c7c1b4308.css" media="all" />`

Comment: It still stays as a comment.

Comment: "Merge CSS files is set to 'NO' "

Comment: In addition to that, you're going against Magento design principles, by taking out the base_url part for some of the values in `System > Configuration > web/unsecure`. If the backend says Merge CSS is "No", clear block html cache. There's clearly 2 css blocks with the IE8 conditional comment in your head and only one stylesheet in top section. It should be referring to skin directory for css, not media and there should be several if merging is off.

Comment: ok. These files in cssmedia/.. are automatically generated by Prototype.js. I think. And there's around 15 files in the same directory with totally random names. I cleared the block html cacke and still no change. I double checked for the merging option in the admin backend and all of it is set to 'NO'.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the template file directly isn't the best option. You can define them via XML this way :

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/styles-ie.css</name>
    <params/>
    <if>lt IE 8</if>
</action>
```

There should already be some pre-defined in `page.xml` if you need an example.

Comment: In my theme I have no page.xml file, I've got a local.xml file. Where should I exactly add it?

Comment: If you don't have a  `<default>` section already, add one. `<default><reference name="head">...the...code...above</reference></default>`

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it still does not work.

Comment: @noSpoon make sure the `<default>` node you created is sitting within the XML's main `<layout>` node if it is not already.

Answer (score 0):

I have made plenty of fixes for IE and have always made them in the head.phtml

Maybe you should try and loading a js alert in the head.phtml like the following so we know that your css call is not the problem and make sure we are working with the correct head.phtml file.

```
<!--[if IE 8]> 
<script>
alert("I'm indeed using IE!");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I know another person commented that you should check and see if your css call is indeed working and loading the css you're trying to call. This should help us narrow down the problem.

Let me know if this works

Comment: Okay. I copied it and paste it into my head.phtml in the current theme and it didn't worked. So I considered that's not the right head.html file and I've tryied all the head.phtml files that I saw. But it remains the same. I also tried changing the IE version to see if there's a problem around that, but still the same.
I have doubts in the IE compatibilty mod, but not sure...
Thank you for the efforts!

Comment: no worries, Maybe try it without the conditional comments just to see which head.phtml is the right one. Also you may want to make sure your cache is turned off and any other full page cache you may have running on your site.

Comment: also I took a look at the page source and found the following conditional comments for  IE7 maybe search your code and see where this is being applied.<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://dev.elmaira.bg/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://dev.elmaira.bg/js/spacer.gif';
 <link href="http://dev.elmaira.bg/skin/frontend/ft001-sofia/mod/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
//]]>
</script>

Comment: No. Conditional comment does not work, declaring the style sheet in the local.xml, page.xml file doesn't work too. If I remove the comment tags, it all works.........